# Finding upper bound for $C^1$ function

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Suppose $\phi: \mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^m$ is $C^1$ and that $s \in \mathbb R^n$. Let $J\phi(x)$ denote the Jacobian of $\phi$ at $x$, which we assume to be invertible for any $x\in \mathbb R^m$.

Now, for distinct $a,b\in \mathbb R^m$ set $F(a,b)= \frac{ \mathbf{\phi}({a})-\mathbf{\phi}({b})-J\mathbf{\phi}({b})({a}-{b})}{\|{a}-{b}\|}$.

Consider the coordinate maps $F=(F_1, \ldots, F_m)$.

> I want to show that $|F_i(a,b)|\leq \frac{K}{2m}$ for each $i=1,
>  \ldots, m$ on some neighborhood of $s$.

I think that $|F_i(a,b)|=\frac{\Big |\phi_i(a)-\phi_i(b)-\Big(\sum_{i=1}^m (a_i-b_i)\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_i}\Big )\Big|}{\|a-b\|}$, where $\phi$ is written in coordinates as $(\phi_1, \ldots, \phi_n)$ and $\frac{\partial \phi_1}{\partial x_i}$ denotes the partial of $\phi_1$ with respect to the $i$-th variable $x_i$.

I'd appreciate if someone could explain the proof.

**UPDATE: Is there something confusing or that doesn't make sense about my question? I'm a bit surprised that it has received no answers, since there very well may be a simple answer I am missing.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\phi$ is of class $C^1$ given $\varepsilon =\frac{K}{4m}$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\Vert J\phi(a)-J\phi(s)\Vert\le \frac{K}{4m}$ for all $a\in B(s,\delta)$. Take $a,b\in  B(s,\delta)$ with $a\ne b$. By the mean value theorem (applied along the segment joining $a$ to $b$ we have
$\phi_i(b)-\phi_i(a)=\nabla \phi_i(c_i)\cdot (b-a)$ and so
$$F_i(b,a)=\frac{ (\nabla \phi_i(c_i)-\nabla \phi_i(b))\cdot (b-a)}{\Vert b-a\Vert}$$
(your formula for $F_i$ is not correct). In turn, 
$$|F_i(b)|\le \Vert \nabla \phi_i(c_i)-\nabla \phi_i(b)\Vert\le \Vert J\phi(c_i)-J\phi(b)\Vert\le \Vert J\phi(c_i)-J\phi(s)\Vert+\Vert J\phi(s)-J\phi(b)\Vert\le \frac{K}{2m}.$$